# How to distribute yearly percentage target to monthly months using Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: problem]

I have base amount 12000 and I convert it to monthly amount 1000. I want to get 20% increase from 12000 which is 14400. The problem is I have to distribute my 20% year target to monthly percentage target (look at the percentage above months). I distributed it according my own preference and have total 20%. But the total is different from expected value which is only 12200 not 14400. Did my method wrong or there is an function to distribute it easily?

Comment: I think it  should like, You have 12000 and you want to achieve 14400, so the difference is 2400. Your base value is 1000, so if you calculate  20% of it, will be 200. Therefore 200*12(months) = 2400, then 12000+2400 = 14400. Means every month you have to earn 200. And 200 is 1.67% of 12000.

Answer (score 0):

Your end result is 200 more than your base amount of 12000
because you’re applying it to the original monthly figures
(12000 ÷ 12 = 1000) and 20% × 1000 = 200. 
You need to apply the percentages to the base amount.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to do is apply a constant monthly percentage increase so that after 12 months, the monthly value has increased by 20%.

The monthly percentage increase needs to be (120% ^ (1/12) - 1), In other words, if you multiply a number 12 times by 120% ^ (1/12), you will end up increasing it by 20%.

The formula to increase the amount in C3 by the required percentage is

```
=C3*(1+20%)^(1/12)
```

You can enter that in the January cell (D3) and copy it to the remaining monthly values.

The following example shows the base amount of $1,000 being increased by a constant percentage in each month (including January), and you will see that by December, it has reached $1,200.

[image]

If you intend the January value to be $1,000 (no increase over the base amount), then change cell D3 to `=C3`. In this case, the monthly amount won't reach $1,200 until January of the next year.